# symfony2 emulate multiple submit buttons with ajax

Tags: jquery, symfony, form-submit, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

there is this new feature of 2.3 with multiple submit buttons
but I'm sending my form with ajax

```
$.post("{{ path('order_ad_banner') }}",
        $('#adOrderForm').serialize() + "&" + $.param({url: "{{ url }}"}),
        function (data) {
            $('#formWindow').html(data);
        }
    );
```

here are my buttons:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
       ....
        ->add('step2submit', 'submit', array('validation_groups' => array("order step 2")))
        ->add('step3submit', 'submit')
        ->add('step4submit', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

how can I emulate submit with 'step2submit' button with ajax?

Edit: Solution found -> add hidden field to the form before post

```
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name",     'adOrder[step2submit]').val("");
    $('#adOrderForm').append(input);
    $.post("{{ path('order_ad_banner') }}",
            $('#adOrderForm').serialize() + "&" + $.param({url: "{{ url }}"}),
            function (data) {
                $('#formWindow').html(data);
            }
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried to trigger `.click()` on the `step2submit` button?

Comment: I don't have this button

Comment: Ok. You can add an answer to this question and accept it in order to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Manipulating the dom maybe not the best solution.
As browsers add the clicked button as another parameter without a value, you can do the same and add it manually to the serialized data, before sending it via ajax. 
With this code you only need to add the 'submit-button' class to your buttons and its more flexible on naming (so if u rename the button in your php code, it will still work).

```
$('.submit-button').on('click', function(){
  var data = $(this).parents('form').first().serializeArray();
  data.push( {'name':$(this).attr('name')});
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(this).parents('form').first().attr('action'),
      dataType: 'html',
      data : data,
      success: function(answer) {
        //do something with the answer
      },
      error: function() {
      },
      complete: function() {
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```